# After editing PATH in ~/bash_profile, no users can log in to centos

Tags: centos, virtualbox, login

The user edited ~/bash_profile to add to the PATH. After logging out, the user can no longer log in, and now no other users can log in. What happens is, after the Centos login screen, and entering the password, it looks like it starts to log in, but then goes back to the log in screen. Centos is running in Virtual Box.

Comment: Really, other users can't login either after someone changed `~/.bash_profile`?  Anyway, this sounds similar to a question on ServerFault, so perhaps those answers will help: http://serverfault.com/questions/94503/login-without-running-bash-profile-or-bashrc

Comment: Yes, it didn't make sense to me because it was the user's own profile that was changed. It appears the other users might have a non-related problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to log in as root. It turns out the user deleted the entire PATH line. I fixed the PATH and the user is now able to log in.